# ReactiveUI + WPF: ViewModelViewHost does not stretch inside its parent

Tags: c#, wpf, reactiveui

I'm trying to get a fresh little reactUI WPF app up and running. However `ViewModelViewHost` causes me problems. It does not fill the widow but stays at its minimum required measures. (as calculated off of its children)

I have this bit of XAML in my MainWindow.xaml:

```
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Name="WorkArea">
        <reactiveUi:ViewModelViewHost  ViewModel="{Binding .}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" DataContext="{Binding DocVm}">
            <reactiveUi:ViewModelViewHost.DefaultContent>
                <Label Content="no file" FontStyle="Italic" FontSize="33" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            </reactiveUi:ViewModelViewHost.DefaultContent>
        </reactiveUi:ViewModelViewHost>
    </Grid>
```

So there is a grid in the MainWindow and the middle part shall be occupied by the `ViewModelViewHost` hence applying Horizontal and VerticalAlignment. I also tired getting rid of the second grid, but no difference. What actually happens (as seen in Snoop) is: The `ViewModelViewHost` complies to the *stretch* setting but its templated part   `PART_CurrentContentPresentationSite`  does not comply. It stays at *Left* + *Top*. What should I do, how was this intended?

Replace the template...

BTW. It also seems not to be enough just to set the `ViewModel`-property in order to have the view binding at the view model. You also have to set the `DataContext`.

Comment: What's the height of the second row in the grid?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the HorizontalContentAlignment and VerticalContentAlignment and set those to stretch.

Comment: Uhh stupid I. It is a ContentPresenter in the end... rightdo. Thanks you relieved me from a big headache over the weekend...